# What could be the cause of Curl error 28 on my live server, but not on my local server while using Codeigniter 3 and PHP curl?

Tags: codeigniter-3, cpanel, php-curl

My codeigniter app is giving Curl error: 28 Failed to connect to 66.45.237.70 port 80 after 15023 ms: Couldn't connect to server error during post request at live server. But at my local server its working fine.

Here is my Code

```
public function send_sms_using_api($api, $contact_no, $sms_content){
            
            if (empty($api)) { return 'API not exist in DB'; }

            $api = str_replace("{CONTACT}",$contact_no,$api);
            $api = str_replace("{MESSAGE}",$sms_content,$api);
    
            $url = "http://66.45.237.70/api.php";
            $number=$contact_no;
            $text=$sms_content;
            $data= array(
            'username'=>"01689655055",
            'password'=>"01689655055",
            'number'=>"$number",
            'message'=>"$text"
            );

            $ch = curl_init(); // Initialize cURL
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            $output = curl_exec($ch);
           
            if(!curl_errno($ch)){
    
              $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
            
              echo 'Took ' . $info['total_time'] . ' seconds to send a request to ' . $info['url'];
            
            } else {
            
              echo 'Curl error: '.curl_errno($ch) . curl_error($ch);
            
            }
        
            return $output;
    }
```